# Creating a variable accessible in a package that is initialized at the import in python

Tags: python

I have been struggling with Google (and with Bing, but I would not recognize that one!) trying to find an answer for this, and I have only found partial solutions.

Essentially my problem is the following. I have a value that needs to be accessible through a complete package, however, this value will be different at each import of the module, so the variable that contains the value will need to be introduced at run time.

I will know the variable pretty soon after importing the module. Ideally the solution will be something like:

```
import mypackage
...
my code
...
mypackage.init(myvalue)
#uses myvalue in the background
mypackage.othermodule()
```

How can I do this or something similar?

Comment: You may want to define a class in your package. When you create an instance of the class you can store your value.

Comment: I will have several classes in my package, I actually want to avoid introducing the value in each constructor of each class of the module. But it is obviously the backup solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to do it.

In the init module you define a variable that is later used by the its functions:

"**init**.py"

```
my_token=""
def set_token(token):
    global my_token
    my_token = token
```

Later on in other module:

"myothermodule.py"

```
from mymodule import my_token
my_function(my_token)
```